# SMTP Mechanism to Disable Out of Office Notifications

Tags: lotus-notes

When sending a mail in Lotus notes, it is possible to configure the "Delivery Options" to prevent Out of Office messages from being sent in response to the e-mail:

[image]

I am writing an application that sends e-mails to Lotus Notes recipients via SMTP. I was wondering if there was a mechanism through which I could activate this behavior? Perhaps an e-mail header?

I do not wish to receive out of office notifications from e-mails generated by my application.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an Auto-Submitted header, as described in [RFC-3834](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834), should work. It is intended to indicate that your message came from an automated process. The RFC states that

> ```
>   Automatic responses SHOULD NOT be issued in response to any
>   message which contains an Auto-Submitted header field (see below),
>   where that field has any value other than "no".
> ```

Of course, there's no guarantee that all receiving systems will respect this.